# How can I do nginx return accept parameters by server_name regex?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to host several websites on ubuntu nginx server, serving content from `/dirs/com.website`. What's wrong with my config? `curl -I` for `http://domain.tld` is redirecting to `301 https://www..tld` instead of `https://www.domain.tld`
Please help :) I'm lost

here's my website conf:

```
server {
    listen                   443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    index               index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name         ~^www\.(?<domain>\w+)\.([(com)(co\.uk)(uk)])$;
    root                /dirs/www/com.$domain;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
server {
    listen                   80;
    listen              [::]:80;
    server_name         ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>\w+)\.(?<tld>[(com)(co\.uk)(uk)])$;
    return              301 https://www.$domain.$tld$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen                   443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    server_name         ~^(?<domain>\w+)\.(?<tld>[(com)(co\.uk)(uk)])$;
    return              301 https://www.$domain.$tld$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You should verify your server name's regexes.  If I'm not mistaken, you've mistaken the usage of the square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over complicating things, `domain.tld` is easily accessible, either through `https://nginx.org/r/$server_name` or `https://nginx.org/r/$host` depending on whether you want to use the host as specified by the client or as matched by NGINX.

Comment: So, is it not possible to direct all TLDs of one domain to one root?

Comment: It is but that's not what your question was about. You're complaining about an invalid redirect from `http://domain.tld` to `https://www..tld` instead of `https://www.domain.tld`. This is in effect a mere redirect to https (www not withstanding).

Comment: From the broken regex perspective, any regex tester would have shown that your problem lies within your regex and not NGINX as suggested by @GerardHPille. At this stage I'd direct you to the ServerFault guidelines, specifically the point about research: https://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice

Comment: isn't the regex correct according to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names ?

Comment: That regex does not do what you expect according to any regular expression engine. See https://regex101.com/r/GAdDHZ/

Comment: thanks a lot
`^www\.(?<domain>\w+)\.(?<tld>(co\.uk)?(com)?(uk)?)$`